# Using a Promise to return java Tinkerpop Gremlin Traversal results

Tags: java, future, gremlin, tinkerpop

I would like to leverage the `.promise(final Function<Traversal<S, E>, T> traversalFunction)` method of a Gremlin `GraphTraversal`. It's not clear to me what function I would use within the promise.

Using the Tinkerpop `Client` object, I do something like this:

```
GraphTraversal myTraversal = g.V().hasLabel("myLabel");
client.submitAsync(myTraversal)
        .thenAccept(result -> {
            List<Map<Object, Object>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
            result.iterator().forEachRemaining(item ->{
                DefaultRemoteTraverser drt = (DefaultRemoteTraverser) item.getObject();
                Map<Object, Object> itemMap = (HashMap) drt.get();
                resultList.add(itemMap);
            });
            outputSuccess(resultList);
        })
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            // handle;
            return null;
        })
```

What would the equivalent look like using .promise()? I looked for a test in the source repo that might provide a clue, but did not see one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the `promise()` can only be use if you are using the `Traversal` as a [remote connection](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-gremlin). It will throw an exception in embedded mode as explained in the [javadoc](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/Traversal.html#promise-java.util.function.Function-).

The `promise()` takes a function that processes the `Traversal` after it has been submitted asynchronously to the server. You're really just providing a terminator to the `promise()` to get a result into the returned `CompletableFuture`:

```
g.V().out().promise(t -> t.toList());
```

I guess you could chain it to be more exactly like what you had in your example:

```
    g.V().out().promise(t -> t.toList()).
      thenAccept(r -> outputSuccess(r)).
      exceptionally(...);
```

Comment: OK, thanks Stephen.. but trying that I get "The method toList() is undefined for the type Object". I could cast t, but I'm not sure what to cast it to, simply Traversal ?

Comment: Ah, I see, it is simply an ArrayList, as returned by toList(). Now I'm jsut getting type safety warnings about "References to generic type CompletableFuture<T> should be parameterized" and I'm having to cast the result, r. I clearly need some type parameters somewhere, but am not sure what and where. I'm kind of weak on generics, especially in this complicate case of a Future with a Function.